# How do I disable Submit button in Amplify Default Auth UI?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, aws-amplify, amplifyjs, aws-amplify-sdk-js

I want to hide the Submit Button in Amplify Default UI, but not sure how to achieve it. Didn't observe any documentation at Amplify.

**Here is my code:**

```
function App() {
  return (
    <AmplifyAuthenticator>
        <AmplifyFormSection  slot="sign-in">
        <AmplifyOauthButton />
        </AmplifyFormSection>
        <div className="App">
        <Users></Users>
      </div>
    </AmplifyAuthenticator>
  );
}
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place the `AmplifyOauthButton` as the slot, just like below:

```js
function App() {
  return (
    <AmplifyAuthenticator>
      <AmplifyOauthButton slot="sign-in" />
    </AmplifyAuthenticator>
  );
}
```

Comment: I tried this solution however I need to wrap the App component with AmplifyAuthenticator for the Authentication process to take place. Any suggestion howe to achieve it ? I updated the code above with the app component that needs to be authenticated.

Comment: Have you tried using the HOC `withAuthenticator`?

Comment: I used it before but didn't find a way to edit the Login Form so to keep the Federated oAuth Login Button and remove everything else. Can you share a code snippet if you have an alternate way to do it ?

Comment: @RanopriyoNeogy I'm sorry for oversimplify the answer. I've edited the answer with the correct way. I've tested here and turns out that you can achieve it just using calling the `AmplifyOauthButton` with the `slot="sign-in"`

Comment: Thanks, @Lucas Yamamoto looks like they removed the AmplifyOauthButton in new versions.. Is there a way to achieve the same functionality now ?